# HXT: Select a node by position with HXT in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, arrows, hxt

I’m trying to parse some XML files with Haskell. For this job I’m using [HXT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT) to get some knowledge about arrows in real world applications. So I’m quite new to the arrow topics.

In XPath (and [HaXml](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaXml/1.24/doc/html/Text-XML-HaXml-Combinators.html#v%3aposition)) it’s possible to select a node by position, let’s say: `/root/a[2]/b`

I can’t figure out how to do something like that with HXT, even after reading the documentation again and again.

Here is some sample code I’m working with:

```
module Main where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core

testXml :: String
testXml = unlines
    [ "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
    , "<root>"
    , "    <a>"
    , "        <b>first element</b>"
    , "        <b>second element</b>"
    , "    </a>"
    , "    <a>"
    , "        <b>third element</b>"
    , "    </a>"
    , "    <a>"
    , "        <b>fourth element</b>"
    , "        <b>enough...</b>"
    , "    </a>"
    , "</root>"
    ]

selector :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree String
selector = getChildren /> isElem >>> hasName "a" -- how to select second <a>?
                       /> isElem >>> hasName "b"
                       /> getText

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let doc = readString [] testXml
    nodes <- runX $ doc >>> selector
    mapM_ putStrLn nodes
```

The desired output would be:

```
third element
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution which I believe selects "/root/a[2]/b" (all "b" tags inside second "a" tag):

```
selector :: ArrowXml a => Int -> a XmlTree String
selector nth =
    (getChildren /> isElem >>> hasName "a")   -- the parentheses required!
    >. (!! nth) 
    /> isElem >>> hasName "b" /> getText
```

(result is `["third element"]`).

Explanation: As I see, `class (..., ArrowList a, ...) => ArrowXml a`, so `ArrowXml a` is a subclass for `ArrowList`. Looking through `ArrowList` interface:

```
(>>.) :: a b c -> ([c] -> [d]) -> a b d
(>.) :: a b c -> ([c] -> d) -> a b d
```

so `>>.` can select a subset of a list using some lifted `[c] -> [d]` and `>.` can select a single item from a list using a lifted function of type `[c] -> d`. So, after children are selected and tags "a" filtered, let's use `(!! nth) :: [a] -> a`.

There's an important thing to note:

```
infix 1 >>>
infix 5 />
infix 8 >.
```

(so I've had a hard time trying to figure out why `>.` without parentheses does not work as expected). Thus, `getChildren /> isElem >>> hasName "a"` must be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great explanation of `(>>.)` and `(>.)`. This was the hint I was missing. There is only one problem with the `(!! nth)`. If the XML file has too few `<a>` elements, there is an error. Use of a helper function `helper a = a >>. (take 1 . drop (nth - 1))` would prevent this.

Comment: I did not want to mess up your answer, but I wanted to share my code for selecting a single element in the tree. Just in case someone has the same problem or want’s some code to play with. You receive the credits ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extension to the answer by [EarlGray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621719). See the explanation of `>>.` and `>.`! After asking the question I recognized that I need to walk through the tree in a special and deterministic way. So this is the solution I’m using for my specific problem. For the case someone else tries to accomplish the same thing, I wanted to share the example code.

Let’s say we want to extract the text of the first `<a>` and the second `<b>`. Not all `<a>` elements have at least two `<b>`s, so the code of [EarlGray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621719) would bail out, because you can’t use the `(!!)` function (empty list!).

Have a look at the function `single` in [Control.Arrow.ArrowList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.3.1.1/doc/html/src/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#single), which is using only the first result of the list arrow:

```
single :: ArrowList a => a b c -> a b c
single f = f >>. take 1
```

We wanted to extract the n-th element:

```
junction :: ArrowList a => a b c -> Int -> a b c
junction a nth = a >>. (take 1 . drop (nth - 1))
```

Now we can use this new arrow to build up the selector. It’s necessary to use parentheses around the stuff we’re going to filter with `junction`, because `junction` modifies an existing arrow.

```
selector :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree String
selector = getChildren -- There is only one root element.
         -- For each selected element: Get a list of all children and filter them out.
         -- The junction function now selects at most one element.
         >>> (getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "a") `junction` 1 -- selects first <a>
         -- The same thing to select the second <b> for all the <a>s
         -- (But we had selected only one <a> in this case!
         -- Imagine commenting out the `junction` 1 above.)
         >>> (getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "b") `junction` 2 -- selects second <b>
         -- Now get the text of the element.
         >>> getChildren >>> getText
```

To extract the value and return a Maybe value:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let doc = readString [] testXml
    text <- listToMaybe <$> (runX $ doc >>> selector)
    print text
```

This outputs `Just "second element"` with example XML file.