# HXT getting first element: refactor weird arrow

Tags: haskell, hxt

I need to get text contents of first `<p>` which is children of `<div class="about">`, wrote the following code:

```
tagTextS :: IOSArrow XmlTree String
tagTextS = getChildren >>> getText >>> arr stripString

parseDescription :: IOSArrow XmlTree String
parseDescription =
  (
   deep (isElem >>> hasName "div" >>> hasAttrValue "id" (== "company_about_full_description"))
   >>> (arr (\x -> x) /> isElem  >>> hasName "p") >. (!! 0) >>> tagTextS
  ) `orElse` (constA "")
```

Look at this `arr (\x -> x)` – without it I wasn't be able to reach result.

- Is there a better way to write `parseDescription`?
- Another question
  is why do I need parentheses before `arr` and after `hasName "p"`? (I
  actually found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798417/hxt-select-a-node-by-position-with-hxt-in-haskell?answertab=active#tab-top))

Comment: You'd better use XPath with package "hxt-xpath" like


````
import "hxt-xpath" Text.XML.HXT.XPath.Arrows (getXPathTrees)

parseDescription = getXPathTrees "//div[@id='company_about_full_description']..." >>> getChildren >>> getText
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proposal using hxt core as you demand.

To enforce the first child, cannot be done through *getChildren* output, since hxt arrows have a specific (>>>) that maps subsequent arrows to every list item of precedent output and not the output list, as explained in the [haskellWiki hxt page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT#Filter_combinators) although this is an old definition, actually it derives from [Category (.) composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt/docs/src/Control-Arrow-ListArrow.html#LA).

*getNthChild* can be hacked from [*getChildren*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt/docs/src/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#ArrowTree) of Control.Arrow.ArrowTree

```
import Data.Tree.Class (Tree)
import qualified Data.Tree.Class as T

-- if the nth element does not exist it will return an empty children list

getNthChild :: (ArrowList a, Tree t) => Int -> a (t b) (t b)
getNthChild n = arrL (take 1 . drop n . T.getChildren)
```

then your parseDescription could take this form:

```
-- importing Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.XmlArrow (hasName, hasAttrValue)

parseDescription = 
    deep (isElem >>> hasName "div" >>> hasAttrValue "class" (== "about") 
          >>> getNthChild 0 >>> hasName "p"
          ) 
    >>> getChildren >>> getText
```

**Update**. I found another way using [changeChildren](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#v%3achangeChildren):

```
getNthChild :: (ArrowTree a, Tree t) => Int -> a (t b) (t b)
getNthChild n = changeChildren (take 1 . drop n) >>> getChildren
```

**Update**: avoid inter-element spacing-nodes filtering non-element children

```
import qualified Text.XML.HXT.DOM.XmlNode as XN

getNthChild :: (ArrowTree a, Tree t, XN.XmlNode b) => Int -> a (t b) (t b)
getNthChild n = changeChildren (take 1 . drop n . filter XN.isElem) >>> getChildren
```

Comment: Trying to get the Nth child from an arrow after getChildren is not clear, since subsequent arrows apply on every individual output list element of getChildren.

Answer (score 4):

It could be something like this with [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

```
import "hxt-xpath" Text.XML.HXT.XPath.Arrows (getXPathTrees)

...

xp = "//div[@class='about']/p[1]"

parseDescription = getXPathTrees xp >>> getChildren >>> getText
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the way you proposed but I intentionally chose to use hxt core to understand it and haskell arrows better. So I need answers on thoose questions I asked.