# How to get first element of getChildren HXT?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

So i'm having an issue with HXT, and i do not know how do i get the first element on that :

```
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#PurchaseableItem"/>
<owl:disjointWith rdf:Description="Hello"/>
<owl:disjointWith rdf:Description="Hello1"/>
<owl:disjointWith rdf:Description="Hello2"/>
<owl:disjointWith rdf:Description="Hello3"/>
<owl:disjointWith rdf:Description="Hello4"/>

<owl:equivalentClass> 
    <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Body"/>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#shutter-speed"/>
            <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">0</owl:cardinality>
        </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
    </owl:Class>
</owl:equivalentClass>
```

I do a `getChildren` which gives me that answer (two get Children) but i don't want have all these information ! I just want the first line of these getChildren ! Which is : `<rdfs:subClassOf.../>`and `<owl:equivalentClass>`

How could i do that ?
Thankfully,

**P.S.:**

By the way,getChildren return a list of children right ? I did the trick to get the first element of getChildren which is : `getChildren >. (!! 0)` and it doesn't work ! Giving me some errors about index too large...

Comment: My guess is that if `!! 0` gives you an "index too large" error, then `getChildren` isn't returning any children.  Can you pipe it into `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe` first, and then handle if it's `Nothing`?  That'd certainly be safer anyway.  Can you also show what code you're using?  Your question is a little vague and a code example is usually the best way to get your point across.

Comment: I'm using the function getChildren of HXT library `http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.0.0/docs/src/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#getChildren` . Maybe i should use the `orElse` function. if it doesnt get anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeated similar question with explanation answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310769/hxt-getting-first-element-refactor-weird-arrow/23326708#23326708).

```
import "hxt" Control.Arrow.ArrowTree (changeChildren, getChildren) 

getNthChild :: (ArrowTree a, Tree t) => Int -> a (t b) (t b)
getNthChild n = changeChildren (take 1 . drop n) >>> getChildren
```

**Update**: easier alternative with hxt-xpath

```
fname = "http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/camera/camera.owl" 

myArrow = readDocument [withValidate no,
                        withCheckNamespaces yes,
                        withSubstDTDEntities no, withHTTP []] fname 
          >>> getXPathTrees "/rdf:RDF/owl:Class[1]" 
          >>> getAttrValue "rdf:ID"

main = do
         results <- runX myArrow
         print results
```

result:

```
["Money"]
```

**Update**: working getNthChild, filtering non-element children

```
import qualified Text.XML.HXT.DOM.XmlNode as XN

getNthChild :: (ArrowTree a, Tree t, XN.XmlNode b) => Int -> a (t b) (t b)
getNthChild n = changeChildren (take 1 . drop n . filter XN.isElem) 
                >>> getChildren
```

then

```
myArrow = readDocument [withValidate no,
                        withCheckNamespaces yes,
                        withSubstDTDEntities no, withHTTP []] fname 
          >>> getXPathTrees "/rdf:RDF" 
          >>> getNthChild 1               -- second child
          >>> getAttrValue "rdf:ID"
```

gives the same result as above.

Comment: I did that and doesn't work for the `<owl:equivalentClass>`, it gives me the same example.

Comment: @Damiii Your xml data is malformed (multirooted) You should wrap it in a root tag, and headed with an xml PI <?xml ...?>

Comment: What do you mean by malformed ? I don't understand .

Comment: This is the one i'm using : `http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/camera/camera.owl`

Comment: @Damiii I have solved the problem with getNthChild, as inter-node spacing figured as children too. See updated answer.

Comment: So it is always the second child from the root tree of a <owl:Class> ?

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear, but what i want it's giving me the xml line. For example, if the parse was on a line : <owl:Class>, it will give that string line, i know there is the available command for HXT which is `xread getChildren`. But it give me all the tree available of getChildren ! What i want to it's having a getChildren but without the children (What i means is, f.e.: <owl:equivalentClass> i just want the <owl:equivalentClass> xml line and not all of his children. I hope i was clear